# Azure DevOps, Query to show all Features which was moved from one Epic to another

Tags: azure-devops

We have a "Catch All" kind of epic in our project and from time to time, we move features from the Catch All to the correct Epic.
The question is how can I find out in a given period which Features moved from "Catch All" to the correct EPIC

Comment: Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the updates of the two Epics. You can try the following steps:

1.Get the removed url of "Catch All" Epic. Here is my PowerShell script sample:

```
$date1 = "2021-04-01T08:54:51.32Z"  //period
$date2 = "2021-04-30T08:54:51.32Z"  //period
$pat = "{PAT}"              //Replace with your PAT
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workItems/{Work item ID}/updates?api-version=6.1-preview.3"   //Replace with your Org, project and Epic id
$relations = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET 
foreach($url in $relations.value){
if( ($url.revisedDate -ge $date1) -and ($url.revisedDate -le $date2) )   //period
{
write-host $url.relations.removed.url
}
}
```

Here is the document about [list work item updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

2.Get the added url of "correct" Epic. Just change `write-host $url.relations.removed.url` to `write-host $url.relations.added.url` and work item id.

```
$date1 = "2021-04-01T08:54:51.32Z"  //period
$date2 = "2021-04-30T08:54:51.32Z"  //period
$pat = "{PAT}"              //Replace with your PAT
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workItems/{Work item ID}/updates?api-version=6.1-preview.3"   //Replace with your Org, project and Epic id
$relations = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET 
foreach($url in $relations.value){
if( ($url.revisedDate -ge $date1) -and ($url.revisedDate -le $date2) )   //period
{
write-host $url.relations.added.url
}
}
```

3.Compare the difference of the two outputs. The work item that appears in the two outputs at the same time is what you want .